# How to position an absolute div within an absolute div statically in the center of the page

Tags: html, css

heres a code pen of what I'm working with: https://codepen.io/marcdaframe/pen/ExajEXK

I want to be able to center the green div in the center of the screen statically and allow it to scroll with the screen, however I can't remove it from this structure.

what is the best way of escaping the absolutely position parents to allow the .abs3 div to be centered statically on the screen

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 4000px;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
}
.abs1{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.abs2{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.abs3{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="abs1">
  <div class="abs2">
    <div class="abs3"/>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.abs3{
  position: fixed;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}`

Comment: Simply changing the position to `fixed` seems to do the trick as described.